# One parent row, multiple child rows in another table. How to get them all in one row?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I volunteer for a local non-profit that gives out toys and food during the holiday season. One way that I am helping them is by putting their gift/food requests online. This way instead of manually entering 1,000 or so names manually into Excel over the course of 15 hours they can simply click on a link and have the whole thing exported in the matter of seconds.

My issue is related to how I can get the data from the database in one query. I believe it is possible but can't quite wrap my head around I can do it.

There is a parent table which contains the family information for the kids who will receive gifts (1 row per family). There is a child table that contains the family's childrens' information (1 row per child, many rows for each parent row). There will be 1-3 children rows for each parent row.

```
PARENT TABLE
-----------------------------
id
name
address
city

CHILDREN TABLE
-----------------------------
parent_id
name
gift1
gift2
gift3
```

I would like to get all of the childrens' information with the parents' information in one row when exporting the data from the database so it can be put into a CSV file. I know I can do this with two separate queries but I don't want to hit the database for each and every family's children if possible.

I've pondered this for an hour or so and can't quite come up with how I would accomplish this. I'm sure I need to join the tables but I am unsure how to differentiate each child and avoid duplicating them instead of getting the next child (if there is one).

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the resultant row to look?  It's a relatively simple pivot table, but it's complicated by the 1:many relationship (hence the names of the columns of the pivot table become critical, so you need to know the max number of children).  Why not just use a second query?  It'll be more flexible...

Comment: "I would like to get all of the childrens' information with the parents' information in one row" - is that one row per child (ie. multiple rows for a single parent), or one row per parent (ie. multiple children for the same parent on the same line)?

Comment: "There will be 1-3 children rows for each parent row." So families with more than three children will miss out?

Comment: @Mark Bannister, actually families with more then 3 children are accommodated. They do their best to help as many families and kids as they can.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question - which was that your pre-condition "There will be 1-3 children rows for each parent row" does not appear to allow for more than 3 children per family.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is a variable number of children per parent, the only way it can be done in `SQL` is presenting all gifts semicolon separated in a single record:

```
SELECT  p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name, ': ', c.gift1, ', ', c.gift2, ', ', c.gift3 SEPARATOR ';')
FROM    parents p
JOIN    children с
ON      c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY
        p.id
```

This will give you something like this:

```
parent      children_and_gifst
Mr. Jones   Alice: teddy bear, candy, drum; Bob: pup, sword, flute
```

, all children and their gifts in one column.

Comment: +1, Good to know I wasn't crazy in not finding the solution I thought existed. This will suffice as I can use a little PHP to accomplish the rest of needs. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful to not have too many child records. `GROUP_CONCAT()` is length-limited (server var `group_concat_max_len`) and will truncate anything that goes past this limit. Default is 1024 bytes.